# reactstate callback is not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

From what I read so far is that setState is ran asynchronously and so you wait and it first the callback method right after. Currently, it does not fire the callback at all. I have a button so far that when clicked it runs the triggerTimer function and I want it so that I change the state of isRunning to true and fire the callback method to start the timer

```
class App extends Component{
 constructor(prop){
    super(prop)
    this.state={
        isRunning: false,
        countdown: 0,
        pauses: 0
    };

    this.triggerTimer = this.triggerTimer.bind(this)
    this.startTimer = this.startTimer.bind(this)
    this.pauseTimer = this.pauseTimer.bind(this)
  }


triggerTimer(){
    console.log("i got hit")
    console.log("isRunning: " + this.state.isRunning)
    var isRunning = this.state.isRunning
    if(isRunning === false){
      this.setState=({
        isRunning: !isRunning,
      },function() {
        console.log("isRunningNow:" + this.state.isRunning)
        this.startTimer()
      });
      
      
      
    }else{
      this.setState={
        isRunning: !isRunning,
        countdown: 0,
        pauses:0
      }
      console.log("interupt and reset timer")
    }
  }
```

Comment: `this.setState({isRunning: !isRunning,},function() {console.log("isRunningNow:"+this.state.isRunning);this.startTimer()});`
give it a try

Comment: I added a semicolon after the console.log and it works. I just don't know what the difference between your code and mines (minus the semicolon).

Comment: may be it's woking before you didn't check well but not sure

Comment: where you defining `var isRunning = this.state.isRunning` and using down `!isRunning`
instead of that you can directly use it like `!this.state.isRunning`

Comment: or you can destruct it from state like `const {isRunning} =this.state;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be a typo that is a valid javascript but not a valid react call.

When you do `this.setState` you cant use `=` right after it otherwise you are giving `setState` a new value.

So see this:

```js
this.setState=({
             ^ REMOVE IT
  isRunning: !isRunning,
},function() {
  console.log("isRunningNow:" + this.state.isRunning)
  this.startTimer()
});
```

```
this.setState={
             ^ REMOVE IT AND WRAP THE OBJECT BETWEEN "(" and ")"
        isRunning: !isRunning,
        countdown: 0,
        pauses:0
      }
```

Some useful resources:

- [JavaScript Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics#language_basics_crash_course)
- [How function works](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp)

Comment: I see difference with the '=' now.